# Did anyone in the 19th century deliberately use bank runs to bankrupt their competitiors like in *Tai-Pan* by James Clavell?

Tags: 19th-century, britain, hong-kong

In James Clavell's semi-historical novel *Tai-Pan*, Dirk Struan and Tyler Brock head two competing British merchant companies that earn their income by trade with China around the time of the Opium Wars: both the characters and their companies are inspired by real people and companies that operated out of Hong Kong, likely William Jardine of Jardine, Matheson & Co. and Lancelot Dent of Dent & Co.  Early in the book, Struan learns that a run engineered by Brock has bankrupted the London bank holding most of his firm's assets.

Are there any real historical examples in the 19th century of someone deliberately provoking a bank run to harm a specific company, family, or person?  I looked into Jardine, Dent, and their companies and couldn't find anything similar, but Clavell could have been inspired by something that happened to others.

Comment: Didn't this happen in Its a Wonderful Life too? Or am I just thinking of the coda to it that a Saturday Night Live skit created?

Comment: @T.E.D. Sort of. At the start of the Great Depression, there’s a run on all the banks in the country, and Bailey Savings and Loan barely survives. This isn’t the fault of any one person. Later, the villain of the movie has tens of thousands of dollars of the bank’s money fall literally into his lap, and makes the decision to steal it. This leaves the bank nearly insolvent, but doesn’t create a run on it. In the movie, the villain goes unpunished, but *SNL* did a parody “deleted scene” where the other characters break into his house and act quite contrary to the Holiday Spirit.

Comment: @Davislor - Here it is, the lost ending to [Its a Wonderful Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw89o0afb2A), where they discover that the 8K they needed to save the bank was in fact taken(/stolen?) by the bank's nemesis, Old Man Potter. I personally choose to believe he also started the self-fufilling rumors about the bank run, since he's the only one who benefits from it.

Comment: @T.E.D. That’s one interpretation. When the movie was made, people would remember that there were runs on all the banks during the Depression. I don’t think the screenwriters or audience would have assumed there to be a single villain responsible, but I would need to watch the scene again to remind myself if anyone said how the run started.

Comment: At least [one person in 1925](https://www.nytimes.com/1925/09/27/archives/accused-of-defaming-bank-carpenter-charged-with-causing-run-on-one.html) was accused of defaming a bank and starting a run on it.